# Using Apache IO Commons in Play 2.2

Tags: java, playframework, apache-commons

I'm trying to import Apache Commons IO 2.4 to Play Framework 2.2. I have this in my project's build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.4"
```

When I run `play compile` I get an error

```
[error] impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded. IvyNode = commons-io#commons-io;2.2
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) java.lang.IllegalStateException: impossible to get artifacts
when data has not been loaded. IvyNode = commons-io#commons-io;2.2
```

Any idea what this means and how to correct it?

Comment: `2.2 != 2.4`! Where does the version "2.2" come from (in your errors)?

Comment: This is the actual error message. I have no idea why there is "2.2" here. But I managed to include io-commons by changing to version 2.2. (`libraryDependencies += "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.2"`)